# How to check if user entered an input or not

Tags: c, if-statement, error-handling, printf

Im using this code to allow the use to enter a numerical value for the variable:

```
float day;
printf("Day?: ");
scanf("%f",&day);
```

how can i make the program produce an error message if the user did not enter ANY value for "Day"??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(scanf("%f",&day) != 1)  
    printf("Error");
```

Comment: `scanf("%f",...)` will scan over leading white-space like `'\n'` given the `"%f"`.  `scanf()` will not return until it sees at least 1 non-white-space. (or EOF).

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()/sscanf()`

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, "%f", &day) != 1) {
   if (buf[0] == '\n') 
     HandleNothingInput(); 
   else 
     HandleBadInput(); 
   }
}
```

`fgets()` typically reads until a <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` is entered.  By using `sscanf()` to parse the buffer, empty inputs ("user did not enter ANY value"), bad input ("abc") are readily detected as the result of `scanf()` will be 0.

---

Alternatives: If you want to insure no additional data is entered, one could use a sentinel:

```
int ch;     
if (sscanf(buf, "%f %c", &day, &ch) != 1) {
```

`atof()` is another approach.